# Set cookies to WebView Control

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, uwp

I have cookies which taken from HttpWebRequest and I need to set these cookies to WebView control to another page.

How can I transfer these cookie to WebView control in windows 8.1 Store app?

Answer (score 8):

I got an [answer on MSDN](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/a451d411-9312-4d40-80ee-112e166144ab/how-to-send-auth-cookie-in-webview-request?forum=winappswithcsharp) and it works well for me.

```
try
{
    Uri baseUri = new Uri(txtURI.Text);
    Windows.Web.Http.Filters.HttpBaseProtocolFilter filter = new Windows.Web.Http.Filters.HttpBaseProtocolFilter();
    Windows.Web.Http.HttpCookie cookie = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpCookie("cookieName", baseUri.Host, "/");
    cookie.Value = "cookieValue";
    filter.CookieManager.SetCookie(cookie, false);

    Windows.Web.Http.HttpRequestMessage httpRequestMessage = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpRequestMessage(Windows.Web.Http.HttpMethod.Get, baseUri);
    wvTest.NavigateWithHttpRequestMessage(httpRequestMessage);

}
catch (Exception oEx)
{
    // handle exception
}
```